# No hay ningún elemento ViewData de tipo 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public class Cliente
{

  .... //los demas atributos

       public Distrito distrito { get; set; }
}
```

Controlador

```
    ClienteManager cm = new ClienteManager();
    DistritoManager dm = new DistritoManager();

public ActionResult ListarCliente(int? cod)
    {
        ViewBag.cod = cod;
        ViewBag.data = new SelectList(dm.listaDistrito(), "codigo", "descripcion");
        return View(cm.listaClientes(cod));
    }

    public ActionResult IngresarCliente() {

        return View(new Cliente());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult IngresarCliente(Cliente e,int? d)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(e);
        ViewBag.d = d;
        ViewBag.data = new SelectList(dm.listaDistrito(), "codigo", "descripcion");
        cm.ingresarCliente(e);
        return RedirectToAction("ListarCliente",new {cod =d});
    }
```

vista

```
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.distrito, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.distrito.codigo, ViewBag.data as SelectList, "Seleccione Distrito")
    </div>
 </div>
```

Si me pueden ayudar con el error.El error completo es : 'No hay ningún elemento ViewData de tipo 'IEnumerable' con la clave 'distrito.codigo'.'

Comment: para que asignas el ViewBag.data en el IngresarCliente() con post si despues realizas un redirect, no necesitas hacerlo deja qe lo realice ListarCliente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes es `IngresarCliente()` como `GET`

```
public ActionResult IngresarCliente() {

    ViewBag.data = new SelectList(dm.listaDistrito(), "codigo", "descripcion");

    var cliente = new Cliente();
    cliente.distrito = new ...();

    return View(cliente);
}
```

cuando editas tambien debes asignar valores por defectos al modelo

Nota: use ... porque no se de que clase se trata esa propiedad districto

Comment: Gracias ! ya pude solucionarlo

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que agregar en el metodo GET y POST la siguiente linea:

```
ViewBag.propiedadId= new SelectList(db.Propiedad, "PropiedadId", "PropertyName");
```